# webdriver.chrome() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on amazon web scraping script in python3 so I used selenium but I got this debug

```
webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I saw solutions to change (chrome to Chrome) but I got this debug also

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

this is my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.chrome()
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn')
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res , 'lxml')
box= soup.find('div',{'class':'a-row padCenterContainer widgetBorder'})
products=box.find_all('div',{'class':'a-section a-spacing-none tallCellView gridColumn5 singleCell'})
for details in products:
    name= details.find('span',{'class':'a-declarative'}).text
    link= details.find('a',{'class':'a-size-base a-link-normal dealTitleTwoLine singleCellTitle autoHeight'}).get('href')
    print(name,link)
```

Comment: Have you downloaded the chrome webdriver?

Comment: Please provide the **entire** error message.

Comment: Can you provide the entire error message so that we can have a better idea about the error that you're getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `Chrome()`, not `chrome()`. Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

You can pass the path to your Chromedriver as well, set executable_path to the location where your chromedriver is located (path to `chromedriver.exe` or, for non-Windows users it's just called `chromedriver`):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: @EslamAhmed I edited my answer with another solution

Comment: I worked but now it doesn't give me any data for the part which I want and give me this message ``` DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:65378/devtools/browser/4ff38b27-22be-4d7d-8fc8-f913a8b1090c ```